# Trying to make website login using visual studio c#

Tags: c#

i want to make website login via website, i dont know how to make messages like "Success Login" Or "Wrong Password"
Btw: Sorry for my bad english.I hope you understand
For faster help you can help me via discord "skullymax#7133"
I will be very happy if you help me :)
I tryed looks for another posts but i found nothing

```
       public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.qyxproject.club/wp-login.php");
        }

        public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
        {
            public void Login(string loginPageAddress, NameValueCollection loginData)
            {
                CookieContainer container;

                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginPageAddress);

                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                var query = string.Join("&",
                  loginData.Cast<string>().Select(key => $"{key}={loginData[key]}"));

                var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(query);
                request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
                var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                requestStream.Close();

                container = request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

                var response = request.GetResponse();
                response.Close();
                CookieContainer = container;
            }

            public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer container)
            {
                CookieContainer = container;
            }

            public CookieAwareWebClient()
              : this(new CookieContainer())
            {
            }

            public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

            protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
            {
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
                request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
                return request;
            }

        }



        private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var inputElements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            foreach (HtmlElement i in inputElements)
            {
                if (i.GetAttribute("name").Equals("log"))
                {
                    i.InnerText = Username.Text;
                }
                if (i.GetAttribute("name").Equals("pwd"))
                {
                    i.Focus();
                    i.InnerText = Password.Text;
                }
            }


            var buttonElements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            foreach (HtmlElement b in buttonElements)
            {
                if (b.GetAttribute("className").Equals("button button-primary button-large"))
                {
                    b.InvokeMember("click");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: “login via website” is rather broad. Are you using ASP.NET? WebForms? MVC? All those frameworks already implement accounts and login; use them and stop trying to implement your own.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
alert("Text Here");
```

in you if statemet were you check if your username/password is correct